# Translate automatically text inside a code file

Tags: c#, translate

I have been looking for a while, and the thing is, I need to translate specific text inside a code, he sent it to me in Russian, and I wanted to know if there is a way, to translate the full file, but only translating the Russian parts. For example here.

```
AddInstructionalStart();
AddInstructionalButton("Следующий режим", 197);
AddInstructionalButton("Предыдущий режим", 196);
AddInstructionalButton("Управление объектом", 194);
AddInstructionalButton("Управление объектом", 195);
AddInstructionalButtonCustom("Увеличить скорость", "t_+");
AddInstructionalButtonCustom("Уменьшить скорость", "t_-");
AddInstructionalButtonCustom("Установить", "t_Y");
AddInstructionalButtonCustom("Отмена", "t_N");
AddInstructionalEnd(1);
```

Is there an automatic way to do it? Or just suck it up and do it manually?

Thanks!!

Comment: Depends if all the code looks like that. What you've shown follows a simple pattern, so you could write a script to extract the Russian bits and use an online translation service to get the English. However, that wouldn't work if you have other code that can't be parsed as easily.

Comment: Some of the code yes, but the russian text is scarse, and there are more than 100 files to search and do, that is my issue hehe

Comment: |Hmm, might be harder then. What you could so is write a script that searches for the most common Russian letters, which would at least help you find the Russian text. Depending on how much you've got, it might then be quicker to replace the text with its translation manually.

Comment: @sandruarmy do you want to support multiple language or just outright translate the source code? if its the former, you can rely on resource file (`.resx`) as suggested by jonash. however, keep in mind that by default it relies on window's locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

Code like this should be rewritten to put any translatable string in one or more separate files. Most often .resx files. That way you can just send the files to a translation agency, and there are various tools that help with translation, If you search a bit you should find some that allow automatic translation with the help of online translation services.

Some refactoring tools allow you to move a string to a resx-file with a simple command, but they still need to be given a name, and that might be difficult if you have no idea what the text means. And you still need to decide which strings are UI-strings, and which are meant for logging or other purposes, and I do not think there is any automated way to do that.